# Amazon S3 URL caching and shortening

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to create public URL for private permission images in S3.
Since Unique URL provided by S3 shows Access Denied when opened publicly , I am using a URL like below to show image in website but problem is that it has Access- Key, Signature etc..

I also need to keep that link active for long period as same link is used up to a day.

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketName/folderName/fileName?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%22fileName%22&AWSAccessKeyId=accessKeyId&Expires=expiryTime&Signature=signatureKey
```

How can I have better URL here which is lesser in length since above URL is also not getting cached in browser side and each request is accessing freshly from S3

For public URL, it should be opened ,but not editable .

```
Do I need to add Open/DownLoad Permission to everyone when calling webservice S3?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I have better URL here which is lesser in length since above URL is also not getting cached in browser side

If you want your url can be cached by browser, you can set `Cache-control` and `Expires` headers when you put object.

> Do I need to add Open/DownLoad Permission to everyone when calling webservice S3?

No, since you have used presigned url.

Comment: ,is it accepted practise to have Amazon accessKey in S3 URL ?

Comment: Yes, it is AWS's design. If you need more secure, try to use IAM accesskey and v4 authentication method here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html

Comment: Since the url contains a signature that is regenerated on every page load, the url cannot be cached.

Comment: @KaiPommerenke Signature in presigned url is not regenerate on every page load. See http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html